# JavaScript Breakpoints Disappear or Unable to set in SPA (ReactJS + C# WebAPI) - Visual Studio 2022

Tags: javascript, debugging, create-react-app, visual-studio-2022, breakpoints

I'm encountering difficulties with setting and using breakpoints in JavaScript within Visual Studio 2022 in a Single Page Application (SPA) project that uses ReactJS for the frontend and C# WebAPI for the backend.

When I try to set a breakpoint in a JavaScript file while the application is running, it doesn't show up. But if I place a breakpoint before I start the application, it's visible.
Yet, as soon as I run the application, the breakpoint disappears.

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2022 versions 17.0.0 and 17.8
- React-scripts version 4.0.2
- Use of async JavaScript functions and react-toolkit

Comment: Could you share some screenshots? Provide more details on the project or how it's setup? Is the problem replicable on a new project, using a msvs template? Where exactly are you breaking and where exactly is it going on 1st break?

Comment: What template did you use for creating a new project?

Comment: WebAPI + ReactJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue, execute the following command:

```
npx update-browserslist-db@latest
```

While reviewing the build log, I came across this message:

```
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run the following command: `npx update-browserslist-db@latest` fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
```

Running the mentioned command solved the problem for me, and I was able to set breakpoints without any issues.